# What Software Can I Uninstall From My Laptop to Free Space ?

Tags: uninstall

I am in a situation where I need to clean up some space in my laptop. The space is so limited now, I am not able to update some programmes that needs updating. Infos as follows :

a. I use my laptop for simple purpose - surfing the net, youtube, open office, etc that are ordinary. I do not play games or watch movies (except through youtube) with my laptop.

b. My laptop is an ACER Aspire

c. Below are the programmes that I have. I do hope some of them can be uninstalled to allow more space in my laptop :

1) Windows 10 Update and Privacy Setting.

2) Realtek High Defination Audio Driver

3) Realtek Ethernet Controller Driver

4) Realtek Card Reader

5) Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - installed Dec 2016

6) Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) - installed Dec 2016

7) Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable x86 - installed Dec 2016

8) Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable x64 - installed Dec 2016

9) Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable x86 - installed Feb 2017

10) Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable x64 - installed Feb 2017

- I don't know why - the 2015 which should be the newest version was installed in 2015, but the 2008 ones was installed recently ?

11) Microsoft OneDrive

12) Microsoft Office 365 -en -us

13) KB4023057 (Publisher - Microsoft Corporation)

14) Intel Trusted Execution Engine

15) Intel Serial IO

16) Intel Proset / Wireless Software

17) Intel Graphic Driver

18) Intel (R) Wireless Bluetooth (R)

19) Intel (R) Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework

20) HP Support Solution Framework (I do not have HP laptop, but use HP printer, not sure if this is needed).

21) AOP Framework

22) ACER UEIP Framework

23) ACER Quick Access

24) ACER Portal

25) ACER Configuration Manager (the publisher is Acer instead of Acer Incorporated, as all above ACER's working. Not sure if this makes a difference)

26) ACER Care Center

26) Driver Setup Utility (publisher Acer Incorporated).

Your reply and advices will be very very very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend removing some of the ACER software.  A lot of them are not used in most situations (Unless you actively use them yourself)  I usually refer to them as "Bloatware" because they tend to take up a considerable amount of space.

Comment: Hi, thank you for kind advice. To be honest, I am not sure if I use the Acer programmes. I normally just surf the internet, check my mailbox (outlook.com), listen to music from youtube, use open office. I think the use of my computer are very basic. Saying that, I am not sure if they are Acer related. From all the Acer's programmes, please could you advice which of them can I safely remove ? Can I remove all of them without effecting the use of my laptop ?

Comment: Then it is probably safe to go ahead and remove some of the more obvious ones.  Like **ACER Care Center, Portal, Quick Access**.  That should clear up some space.

Comment: Thank you so very much for kind advice. I have done so accordingly and have saved some space ! :) Thank you.

Comment: Go ahead and remove 13) KB4023057 (Publisher - Microsoft Corporation). To me this is MS malware eating up your CPU.
 I have removed it from my laptop. The same goes for KB4056254.
 I don't have that one installed either on my computer.
An easy way to remove it is to open `cmd.exe` as admin and run:
 `wusa /uninstall /kb:4023057`. You will have to restart your computer.

Comment: Also see https://www.askwoody.com/tag/kb-4023057/.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the Visual C++ Runtimes. You may run into other programs that may use them.
Remove the ACER software as suggested earlier. These programs though, do not consume much space on the computer to make a noticeable difference.

From within windows you can run "Disk Cleanup" to clear out items such as:

Temporary Internet Files, Windows Update Cleanup Files, etc...You may regain some of your space in this manner.

If you have files stored within the Documents, Pictures, or Downloads sections, you may see if you can perform a backup to hard drive/flash drive/DVD if possible and remove them off the computer to free up space until you can update. Then you can copy them back onto the computer.

Comment: Hi, thank you so so very much for your kind advice. I did as you adviced - clean up using 'Disk Cleanup' and I have managed to safe about 4gb which is alot to me. Thank you. As for the Acer's programme, I would really like to uninstall some, but not sure which are safe to uninstall ? Could you advice on this please ?